# Set Image source from pipe in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to implement a custom pipe like below

```ts
@Pipe({
   name: 'imagePipe'
})

@Injectable()
export class ImagePipe {
  constructor(public someService: SomeService, public storage: Storage) {
} 

  transform(value: any, arg: any) {
     if ((value != null) && (value!=arg)){
            return this.storage.get(value).then((val) => {
                            console.log('Your source is', val);

                })
    }
  }
}
```

The purpose of this pipe is to search for a value in storage and set the URL of an image. I am applying it like below:

```html
<img src="{{info.title | imagePipe : otherTitle | async}}" width="45" height="120"/>
```

The console shows a value but the image URL is null.

Comment: Try piping your image pipe into the `async` pipe.

Comment: @pe8ter is correct, may be `info.title | imagePipe : otherTitle | async`

Comment: `val` is resolved asynchronously, you return a promise not a string from the pipe.

Comment: only 'async' does not work,  maybe I need to modify my pipe as well

Comment: Your transform method doesn't return anything. Add `return ` before `this.storage...`.

Comment: added 'return' and 'async'..no result

Comment: But now you removed the return from inside the then callback, so you're returning a Promise of undefined.

Comment: resolved the issue, problem was with the return statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 errors in this:

```
     if ((value != null) && (value!=arg)){
        return this.storage.get(value).then((val) => {
                        console.log('Your source is', val);

            })
}
```

first of all, the if its false you don't return anything!
second, I would load storage.get in a "class var" and call it from there...

Answer (score -1):

The solution is

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'imagePipe'
})

@Injectable()
    export class ImagePipe {
        constructor(public someService: SomeService, public storage: Storage) {} 

        transform(value: any, arg: any) {
             if ((value != null) && (value!=arg)){
                  return this.storage.get(value).then((val) => {
                        console.log('Your source is', val);
                        return val;
            })
        }
    }
 }
```

The return statements were wrong